# Trigger another Jenkins pipeline to build in parallel after a certain stage in one pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have two Jenkins pipelines A and B. After the third stage of A, I want to trigger B and let it run in parallel with the rest of the stages of A. Is there a way to configure A's Jenkinsfile so that I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pipeline A in the stage just call build like so

```
node {
parallel(firstTask: {
  stage 'B1'
  // build 'PipelineB' // name of the pipeline
}, secondTask: {
  stage 'B2'
  // Do some other stuff in parallel
})
Stage('C') {
      //final steps
}
```

To do the same using DSL refer here https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/